# Struts redirection from action to Jsp and back again to same action class giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have created action classes and jsp's using affuse frame work. But problem is when i am working with redirections exmple when we press add button in jsp fReleaseList.jsp redirects to  action class is FReleaseAction.java and initializes instance variable "fRelease" and redirects to fReleaseForm.jsp and when save button is pressed it agin redirects to same action class 
FReleaseAction.java and there the "fRelease" variable will be null. Config file for this is as bellow,

/WEB-INF/pages/fReleaseList.jsp

```
    <action name="editFRelease" class="com.vxl.appanalytix.webapp.action.FReleaseAction" method="edit">
        <result>/WEB-INF/pages/fReleaseForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/pages/fReleaseList.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="saveFRelease" class="com.vxl.appanalytix.webapp.action.FReleaseAction" method="save">
        <result name="input">WEB-INF/pages/fReleaseForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="cancel" type="redirectAction">fReleases</result>
        <result name="delete" type="redirectAction">fReleases</result>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">fReleases</result>
    </action>
    <!--FReleaseAction-END-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Unless you use that variable in the form, Struts doesn't send the value back.
In order to send the values back, you need to set HiddenVariable in the jsp page

In simple, if you have textbox like this 
When JSP page is generated, a Hidden variable is generated by struts and when you submit the form, the hidden variable data will be transformed and stored/mapped to Bean data.

If you are not using Bean variable in the jsp page, Struts doesn't generate the hidden variable type for that, thus when it goes to Action class, it will create the new bean and the old bean data is not set.